# Gnome 44 Activities Overview No Longer Working

Tags: gnome, activities-overview

I am hoping that someone can help me with a recent problem that has sprung up today.  I booted my system, which was running Ubuntu 22.10 and there were major changes to the desktop.  The bottom task bar was gone, the background had changed (to default Ubuntu from black), and the Super key no longer brought up Activities Overview.

I have tried the "upper left corner" mouse position to activate Activities Overview but that does not bring anything up either.  The upper left hand corner now has a new "applications" menu.

I have confirmed that my super key is not disabled as it works to lock the screen as usual.  I figure that something must have gone through an upgrade yesterday and things under the hood got changed.  I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04 to see if that would help, and nothing changed (at least visually).

I was wondering if this might just be something that I screwed up without knowing it or whether it might be something more widespread.
Please let me know if there is any more information that I can provide that is helpful.  The "About" information from settings is below.  Thank you so much!

-John

Installation information:
Hardware model: MSI Creator 17 A10SFS

Firmware version: E17G3IMS.310

Memory: 32GB

Processor: Intel i7-10875H

Graphics: Nvidia RTX 2070

OS Name: Ubuntu 23.04

GNOME Version: Not Available (should be 44)

Windowing System X11

Kernel Version: Linux 6.2.0-20-generic

Screenshot of upper left of desktop showing applications and places but no "activities"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to fix the problem, thought I don't know why it broke in the first place (too inexperienced with Linux).  I figured that the system tried to upgrade automatically to Gnome 44, and got a bad install.  I removed gnome-shell, then reinstalled it.  This brought back the activities overview.  I then installed gnome-extensions and gnome-extensions-manager, which allowed me to then install the extensions that were active before things broke.  Things are pretty much back to normal now; still not 100% sure what exactly broke, but as long as it's working, I guess I can't complain :).